# Pop-up not working with Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm completely new to Ajax, but trying to get a feedback module for django working, which is a tab that pulls out for users to submit feedback.

Here's the template:

```
<div id="feedback_button" class="white left normal"><a href="/feedback/">feedback</a></div>
<div class="hiding">
<div id="feedback_popup" class="colorbox" style="width: 500px">
    <h1>Feedback</h1>
    {% if not feedback_text %}
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0">We would be happy to consider any feedback you have.</p>
    {% else %}
        {{feedback_text}}
    {% endif %}
    <form class="feedback" action="{% url feedback.views.handle_ajax %}" method="POST" style="margin: 0">{% csrf_token %}
        <div style="display: none"><input name="body" value="..."/></div>
        <label for="email">email (optional)</label>
            <input name="email" value="{{user.email}}"/>
             <div class="email error"> </div>
        <label for="subject">subject (optional)</label>
            <input name="subject"/>
             <div class="subject error"> </div>
        <label for="text">message</label>
            <textarea name="text"></textarea>
            <div class="text error"> </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button>Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="thanks hiding">Thank you for your feedback!</div>
    <div class="general error hiding"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        feedback.init({
            'button':$('#feedback_button'),
            'drop':$('#feedback_drop'),
            'popup':$('#feedback_popup')
        });
        if (document.cookie == "") {
            // CSRF protection requires a cookie to be set already.
            $('#feedback_button').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I see the feedback button, however when I click on it, nothing happens. Because I'm a newbie to jquery/ajax, not really sure as to where to start debugging this... any hints?

Here is where I call it in the `base.html` template:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
    {% include "feedback/button.html" %}
        <div id="wrapper">
```

Here's the relevant jquery:

```
var feedback = {};
feedback.init = function(config) {
    if (!(config.button && config.drop && config.popup))
        throw "invalid params";
    config.popup.find('form.feedback').ajaxSubmit({
        'onstart':function(){
            config.popup.addClass('loading');
        },
        'onend':function(){
            config.popup.removeClass('loading');
        },
        'onerror':function(why){
            alert('Error! '+why);
        },
        'onsuccess':feedback.done(config)
    });

    config.button.click(function(){
        config.drop.removeClass('hiding');
        config.popup.removeClass('hiding');
        config.popup.find('input[name=email]').focus();
    });
    config.popup.find('.close').click(feedback.closeit(config));
};
```

Comment: Can you tell us where feedback.init comes from is it a jquery plugin attached ?

Comment: Yes, just added this. It's a jquery plugin. I checked to make sure all the jquery plugins it's loading are available in my static directory.

Comment: Can you please send us the plugin home page or etc.

Comment: OK it seems you properly added codes as https://github.com/jabapyth/django-feedback/tree/45d20665744d98ff75b40b0a81333392521c8d94 readme says but this doesnt make sense can i see your end page html is it on the net or local

Comment: It's local right now but I could put it on the net if you want to look.

Comment: The only way for me to debug your page is this, so after you make your page reachable for me, i can take care of that

Comment: Ok give me 10 min -- to  collectstatic and to push the code... thanks so much...

Comment: I notice that the plugin also causes some other jQuery plugins to not work on other pages which I find odd.

Answer (score 0):

- Your JS attachment `/static/uni_form/uni-form.jquery.js` is not being loaded - returns 403 Forbidden
- In main.js at line `config.popup.find('form.feedback').ajaxSubmit({` ajaxSubmit returns an error . Maybe you would put `feedback.init` or all main.js between an `$(document).ready(function(){...});` etc... However make sure ajaxSubmit is available at that execution point.

Comment: Ok I fixed the uni-form problem but tried the second solution but it's not seeming to make a differece.... I tried both ways-- wrapping just `feedback.init` and then all of `main.js` in a document ready function...

Answer (score 0):

ajaxSubmit() will submit the form right away. 
Use ajaxForm() and: a submit button, or wire up the button click event to perform submit().
Or do the ajaxSubmit() during button click event. 
Something like this should work (not tried)...

```
feedback.init = function(config) {
    if (!(config.button && config.drop && config.popup))
        throw "invalid params";
    config.popup.find('form.feedback').ajaxForm({
        'onstart':function(){
            config.popup.addClass('loading');
        },
        'onend':function(){
            config.popup.removeClass('loading');
        },
        'onerror':function(why){
            alert('Error! '+why);
        },
        'onsuccess':feedback.done(config)
    });

    config.button.click(function(){
        config.drop.removeClass('hiding');
        config.popup.removeClass('hiding');
        config.popup.find('input[name=email]').focus();
        config.popup.find('form.feedback').ajaxSubmit();
    });
    config.popup.find('.close').click(feedback.closeit(config));
};
```